# Net Core: Do Static Classes need ISerializable from SonarQube?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, .net-core, sonarqube

Does anyone understand this error in Sonarqube? We want to implement a grid requirement dimension- given a number of pictures. 2 picture is 1X2 grid, 4 pictures is 2X2, 6 pictures are 3X2, etc. Sonarqube is requesting to implement Serializable for such simple static classes. How would I fix this, and is it necessary?

**Current Code:**

```
public class CardDimensionRequirement:Dictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine> 
{
    public void AddItem(int PictureCount, int Length, int Height, int BootstrapDimension)
    {
        base.Add(PictureCount, new CardDimensionRequirementLine(PictureCount, Length, Height, BootstrapDimension));
    }

    public int GetMaxKey()
    {
        return base.Keys.Max();
    }    
}

static class CardDimensionRequirementSpecs
{
    public static CardDimensionRequirement cardDimensionRequirementData;

    static CardDimensionRequirementSpecs()
    {
        //int PictureCount, int Length, int Height, int BootstrapDimension
        cardDimensionRequirementData = new CardDimensionRequirement();
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(1, 1, 1, 1);
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(2, 2, 1, 6);
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(3, 3, 1, 4);
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(4, 2, 2, 6);
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(5, 3, 2, 4);
        cardDimensionRequirementData.AddItem(6, 3, 2, 4);
    }
}
```

[image]

**SonarQube Recommendation:**

```
The ISerializable interface is the mechanism to control the type serialization process. If not implemented correctly this could result in an invalid serialization and hard to detect bugs.

This rules raises an issue on types that implement ISerializable without following the serialization pattern recommended by Microsoft.

Specifically this rule checks for these problems:

The System.SerializableAttribute attribute is missing.
Non-serializable fields are not marked with the System.NonSerializedAttribute attribute.
There is no serialization constructor.
An unsealed type has a serialization constructor that is not protected.
A sealed type has a serialization constructor that is not private.
An unsealed type has a ISerializable.GetObjectData that is not both public and virtual.
A derived type has a serialization constructor that does not call the base constructor.
A derived type has a ISerializable.GetObjectData method that does not call the base method.
A derived type has serializable fields but the ISerializable.GetObjectData method is not overridden.

Noncompliant Code Example
public class Foo : ISerializable // Noncompliant the [Serializable] attribute is missing
{
}
or

public class Bar
{
}

[Serializable]
public class Foo : ISerializable // Noncompliant the serialization constructor is missing
{
    private readonly Bar bar; // Noncompliant the field is not marked with [NonSerialized]
}

Compliant Solution
public class Bar
{
}

[Serializable]
public class Foo : ISerializable
{
    [NonSerialized]
    private readonly Bar bar;

    public Foo()
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected Foo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

[Serializable]
public sealed class SubFoo : Foo
{
    private int val;

    public SubFoo()
    {
        // ...
    }

    private SubFoo(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        // ...
    }
}
Exceptions
Classes in test projects are not checked.
```

Comment: It's probably spitting out this error because your base class, [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8), implements `ISerializable` and applies `[Serializable]`.  Try implementing `IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>` and containing your dictionary inside as a private member and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Also, do you need to serialize your type via `BinaryFormatter` and/or a data contract serializer?

Comment: hi @dbc  how did you know Dictionary implements ISerializable? the problem is fixed ! did you remember on top of your head?  Feel free to place in answer and I can give points, want to be able to learn myself , you seemed to ignore Sonarqube solution, and found the true work around, sometimes code analyzers are incorrect

Comment: I can write an answer.  One question: did you end up implementing `ISerializable` or just implementing `IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>` directly instead?

Comment: @dbc second option IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube is likely giving that error because your base type, [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8), *implements custom binary serialization* via the [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization#implementing-the-iserializable-interface) interface.  Given that your base type implements custom serialization, SonarQube appears to be making the assumption that you need to override that custom serialization to add serialization of your derived type's declared members.

Your type, however, declares no fields or properties of its own, and so has nothing specific to serialize.

So, what are your options to resolve the issue?

**If you don't care about binary serialization** and don't need to support it, you could adopt the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and implement `IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>` rather than deriving from `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.  Then, inside `CardDimensionRequirement` have some private dictionary to do the actual lookups:

```
public class CardDimensionRequirement : IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>
{
    readonly Dictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>();

    public void AddItem(int PictureCount, int Length, int Height, int BootstrapDimension)
    {
        Add(PictureCount, new CardDimensionRequirementLine(PictureCount, Length, Height, BootstrapDimension));
    }

    public int GetMaxKey()
    {
        return Keys.Max();
    }   

    #region IDictionary<int,CardDimensionRequirementLine> Members

    // Delegate everything to this.dictionary:

    public void Add(int key, CardDimensionRequirementLine value)
    {
        this.dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    // Remainder snipped
```

Do not mark the class as `[Serializable]` or implement `ISerializable`.

An advantage of this implementation is that switching to a different dictionary, say `SortedDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>`, would not be a breaking change.

**If you do care about binary serialization** you should mark your type as `[Serializable]`, override [`GetObjectData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getobjectdata?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2_GetObjectData_System_Runtime_Serialization_SerializationInfo_System_Runtime_Serialization_StreamingContext_), and introduce your own [streaming constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Runtime_Serialization_SerializationInfo_System_Runtime_Serialization_StreamingContext_) like so:

```
[Serializable]
public class CardDimensionRequirement : Dictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>
{
    public CardDimensionRequirement() : base() { }

    protected CardDimensionRequirement(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        // Nothing to do since your class currently has no fields
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
        // Deserialize fields here, if you ever add any.
    }

    // Remainder snipped
```

**As an alternative**, since your `CardDimensionRequirement` doesn't actually have any of its own data to remember, you could simply use any old `Dictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine>` and implement your methods as extension methods:

```
public static class CardDimensionRequirementExtensions
{
    public static void AddItem(this IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine> dictionary, int PictureCount, int Length, int Height, int BootstrapDimension)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        dictionary.Add(PictureCount, new CardDimensionRequirementLine(PictureCount, Length, Height, BootstrapDimension));
    }

    public static int GetMaxKey(this IDictionary<int, CardDimensionRequirementLine> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return dictionary.Keys.Max();
    }   
}
```

Comment: My question would be why SonarQube can't figure this out itself. I have a class file that ONLY has `public class MyClass : Dictionary<string, object> {}`, not methods, fields of anything else